# Why is my laptop fan running so much?

Tags: dell, fan

I have a Dell N5110 laptop and the fan is running quickly and noisily often. I'm concerned my laptop might be getting damaged.

Is there any way to identify what is causing this and, if so, how I might fix it safely?

Comment: please `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors` and paste the output of the `sensors` command, preferably when the system is idling, so we can see the typical temperature of your processor and (depending on the hardware) information about the fan speed

Comment: It may also help to know what version of Ubuntu you're running.

Answer (score 2):

you should consider installing jupiter

you can select power modes with it, its very easy to controll, and I just set it to power on command, you wont notice that your laptop is on, until you start using heavy apps

open terminal and do this.

add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
```

update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

install jupiter

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

and to other people reading this and are using an Asus EEPC netbook, install this asswell

```
sudo apt-get install jupiter-support-eee
```

Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [earlier questions](https://superuser.com/q/392098/47108), it looks like your laptop is one of those hybrid laptops that have an integrated (Intel) and discrete (Nvidia) GPU. You probably do not need a lot graphical power, so if your BIOS has an option to choose for the Integrated card (disable Optimus mode), do so. Alternatively, you can install [Bumblebee](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) which is described in [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)